# Configure SMOTE for Vector Prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, smote

I am working in a multi-label prediction task where the label is encoded as one-hot encoded vector such as `[1, 0, 0]` or `[0, 1, 0]` or `[0, 0, 1]` of type `ndarray`.

The dataset is imbalanced. Hence, I am using SMOTE. This works and upsamples all minority classes (it upsamples as many records as the majority class holds).

Now, I want to upsample not as many records. According to the [documentation](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html), I can use `sampling_strategy` and provide a dict with `key = class label` and `value = total records`.

However, I cannot add the `ndarray` as key to my dict (`TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`). What is the best way here? SMOTE can obviously handle these one-hot encoded vectors -- so how do I get the `total records` in there?